# Как имитировать нажатие на кнопку несколько раз последовательно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

В jquery есть метод trigger для имитации события click например. Но оно работает однократно, т.е. кнопка нажимается один раз. А как сделать чтобы кнопка нажималась три раза, например?

```
$('button').trigger('click'); /*нажимается 1 раз*/
$('button').trigger('click').trigger('click').trigger('click'); /*все равно нажимается 1 раз*/
```

Comment: а если использовать setInterval()? или вам нужен именно такой стиль?

Comment: не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос много раз